# GraphQL update multiple statusses

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

For my project I need to update the status for all posts where the status is currently 1.

I've been trying to find a way to create a condition based mutation, or maybe even put multiple mutations in one request (though this has the disadvantage that I need to have the id's of all posts with status = 1 in advance.

Can't seem to find any solution beside mutating every item individually, which seems extremely inefficient to me.

Comment: one time? use db tool like phpmyadmin

Comment: No based on a user action in the GUI.

Comment: create mutation and resolver to do it on backend

Comment: Ah yes that does the trick, sorry I'm not very proficient with GraphQL / Laravel yet. I now have a custom updateStatus mutation. Do you know if there is any way to do this client side, for example with a query like this:

`mutation invite_users {
  update_status (
    where: {status: 1}
  ) {
    users {
      id
    }
  }
}`

Comment: no, id doesn't make sense on client side - no changes in DB on backend ... you can pass this filter as parameter (object) to backend/resolver (to be interpreted) ... but at start it would be simpler to create mutation with hardcoded logic (conditions) 'inviteAllWithStatusOne'